# Why is 1 assigned to a hash element?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures, perl-hash

Could any one explain what this statement does in Perl

```
$type{$_->{brand}} = 1;
```

I could understand that the hash `%type` has a key `brand` holding the reference to another hash `brand` and **1 is assigned to it**

what does it mean??!!! when it is assigned as 1?

```
package SillyFunction;

sub group_products {
    my $products = shift;
    my %brand_type = ();
    my $grouped_products = [];

    foreach (@{$products}) {
        $brand_type{ $_->{brand} } ||= {};
        $brand_type{ $_->{brand} }->{ $_->{type} } = 1;
    }

    foreach (sort keys %brand_type) {
        my $brand = $_;
        foreach (sort keys %{ $brand_type{$brand} }) {
            push(@{$grouped_products}, { brand => $brand, type => $_ });
        }
    }

    $grouped_products;
}
1;
```

Comment: Almost nothing you said there makes any sense. Have you been through a Perl tutorial? Where did you hear about a "hash function" and assigning something "to 1"?

Comment: package SillyFunction;

sub group_products {
my $products = shift;
my %brand_type = ();
my $grouped_products = [];

foreach (@{$products})
{
$brand_type{$_->{brand}} ||= {};
** $brand_type{$_->{brand}}->{$_->{type}} = 1; **
}
foreach (sort keys %brand_type)
{
my $brand = $_;
foreach (sort keys %{$brand_type{$brand}}) {
push(@{$grouped_products}, { brand => $brand, type => $_});
}
}
$grouped_products;
}

1;

Comment: This is the code I am talking about. in the the code $brand_type{$_->{brand}}->{$_->{type}} = 1; Whats that mean??!! hash is assigned to digit 1 @Wooble

Comment: Nothing is being assigned to 1, 1 is being assigned to a hash element. To break it down, $_ presumably holds a hash reference, so `$_->{brand}` is retrieving the value associated with "brand" in that hash, then using it as a hash key to select an element in the hash %type (which appears as $type here because it is the scalar in the hash being accessed) and setting that element to 1. The use of $_ suggests this was in a loop but since you didn't show that, we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
$type{$_->{brand}} = 1;
```

means:

- We have a variable of the type hash, named `%hash`.
- The *topic variable* `$_` contains a *reference* to a hash.
- We access the entry called `brand` in the hash referenced by `$_`. We remember this value.
- We access the entry with the name we just remembered in the hash named `%hash`.
- Hash elements are *lvalues*, i.e. something can be assigned to them.
- We assign the number `1` into the hash slot we just accessed.

Points to note:

- In Perl, a hash is a data structure. Other languages know this as an *associative array*. It maps strings to scalar values.
- A hash function calculates a characteristic number for a given string. The hash data structure uses such a function internally, and in a way inaccessible from Perl. Hash functions are also important in cryptography.
- The `=` operator assigns the thing on the right to the thing on the left.
- That line of code has not a single keyword, only variables (`%type`, `$_`), constants (`'brand'`, `1`) and operators (`{...}`, `->`, `=`, `;`).

Here is the code you posted in your comment, annotated with comments:

```
# Declare a namespace "SillyFunction".
# This affects the full names of the subroutines, and some variables.
package SillyFunction;

# Declare a sub that takes one parameter.
sub group_products {
  my $products = shift;

  my %brand_type = ();       # %brand_type is an empty hash.
  my $grouped_products = []; # $grouped_products is a reference to an array

  # loop through the products.
  # The @{...} "dereferences" an arrayref to an ordinary array
  # The current item is in the topic variable $_
  foreach (@{$products}) {
    # All the items in $products are references to hashes.
    # The hashes have keys "brand" and "type".

    # If the entry if %brand_type with the name of $_->{brand} is false,
    # Then we assign an empty hashref.
    # This is stupid (see discussion below)
    $brand_type{$_->{brand}} ||= {};

    # We access the entry names $_->{brand}.
    # We use that value as a hashref, and access the entry $_->{type} in there.
    # We then assign the value 1 to that slot.
    $brand_type{$_->{brand}}->{$_->{type}} = 1;
  }

  # We get the names of all entries of %brand_type with the keys function
  # We sort the names alphabetically.
  # The current key is in $_
  foreach (sort keys %brand_type) {
    # We assign the current key to the $brand variable.
    # This is stupid.
    my $brand = $_;

    # We get all the keys of the hash referenced by $brand_type{$brand}
    # And sort that again.
    # The current key is in $_
    foreach (sort keys %{$brand_type{$brand}}) {
      # We dereference the ordinary array from the arrayref $grouped_products.
      # We add a hashref to the end that contains entries for brand and type
      push(@{$grouped_products}, { brand => $brand, type => $_});
    }
  }

  # We implicitly return the arrayref containing all brands and types.
  $grouped_products;
}

# We return a true value to signal perl that this module loaded all right.
1;
```

What does this code do? It takes all products (a product is a hashref containing a field for brand and type), and sorts them primarily by brand, secondarily by type, in alphabetic, ascending order.

While doing so, the author produced horrible code. Here is what could have gone better:

- He uses an arrayref instead of an array. It would have been easier to just use an array, and return a reference to that:

  ```
  my @grouped_products;
  push @grouped_products, ...;
  return \@grouped_products; # reference operator \
  ```
- At some point, an hashref is assigned. This is unneccessary, as Perl *autovivicates* undefined values that you use as a hash or array reference. That complete line is useless. Also, it is only assigned if that value is false. What the author probably wanted is to assign if that value is *undefined*. The defined-or operator `//` could have been used here (only since perl5 v10 or later).
- A hash of hashes is built. This is wasteful. A hash of an array would have been better.
- If one loops over values with `for` or `foreach`, the current item doesn't *have* to be assigned to the cryptic `$_`. Instead, a loop variable can be specified: `foreach my $foo (@bar)`. The default behaviour of `foreach` is similar to `foreach local $_ (@bar)`.
- Implicit returns are bad.

Here is a piece of code that implements the same subroutine, but more perlish — remember, we just wanted to sort the products (assuming they already are unique)

```
sub group_products {
  my ($products) = @_;
  my @grouped =
    # sort by brand. If that is a draw, sort by type.
    sort { $a->{brand} cmp $b->{brand} or $a->{type} cmp $b->{type} }
    map  { +{%$_} } # make a copy.
    @$products;     # easy dereference
  return \@grouped;
}
```

<sub>**Explanation:** This code is largely self-documenting. The `sort` function takes a block that has to return a number: Either negative for “`$a` is smaller than `$b`”, zero for “`$a` and `$b` are equal”, or positive for “`$a` is larger than `$b`”.</sub>

<sub>The `cmp` operator compare the operands lexigraphically. If the brands are different, then we don't have to compare the types. If the brands are the same, then the first `cmp` returns `0`, which is a false value. Therefore, the second comparision (type) is executed, and that value returned. This is standard Perl idiom for sorting by primary and secondary key.</sub>

<sub>The `sort` and `map` cascade executes from right/bottom to left/top.</sub>

If the uniqueness is not guaranteed, something like this would work better:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;
sub group_products {
  my ($products) = @_;
  my %grouping;
  push @{ $grouping{ $_->{brand} } }, $_->{type} for @$products;
  my @grouped;
  for my $brand (sort keys %grouping) {
    push @grouped, +{brand => $brand, type => $_} for sort uniq @{ $grouping{$brand} };
  }
  return \@grouped;
}
```

<sub>**Explanation:** We define a `%grouping` hash (to be filled). For each product, we add the type of that product to the arrayref of the appropriate brand in the grouping hash. That is, we collect all types for each brand. We define an array of all grouped products (to be filled). We iterate through all brands in alphabetical order, and then iterate through all unique products of that brand in alphabetical order. For each of these brand/type combinations, we add a new hashref to the grouped products. The `uniq` function is imported from the excellent `List::MoreUtils` module. We return a reference to the array of grouped products.</sub>

Comment: Could I know write a unit test for the above subroutine. could you explain the logic plz. -amon

Comment: @KuladeepParella I added some explanations. However, the contract of my functions is the same as the one you posted, so they should pass existing unit tests for the old subroutine. **Further Hints:** If you're new to Perl, you might enjoy http://perltuts.com/ . If you end up using substantial portions of my post, remember that all StackOverflow content is licensed under cc-by-sa 3.0 (see footer of this site for details).